Could the Romans transport a Live Octopus from the East African Coast to Rome?
Quick Lore Explanation
In my world, a sapient species of Octopus evolved in Australia. They have their shenanigans there, but later find out a way to cross the Indian Ocean to get to Africa, where they live a nomadic life depending on the changing water temperature during the seasons (In the winter when there is colder water temperatures they go up the coast, and in the summer where that coast is too warm they come back down to the Southern tip of Africa.). They have feuds with Fishermen, sinking their boats and just generally interfering with any human activities related to the water
Basically, there is sapient octopus that live on the coasts of Southern and East Africa.
Now according to this map below, during the 1st Century AD, the Romans traveled and traded as far south as modern-day Tanzania, whose coast these Octopus would inhabit during the winter. 
Some adventurous Travelers or Merchants return from the East African coast with tales of Octopus the size of men attacking fisherman boats with tridents and interacting with an odd friendly human or two. A Roman Emperor hears of these tales and becomes obsessed with the idea of having one of those  Colosseum naval battles but with the octopuses.
So they send out an expedition to Rhapta on the East African Coast to retrieve one of these Sapient Octopus for them.
My question here in this post is if it is possible for Romans, with 1st century AD tech, to be able to get the Octopus from the waters of East Africa to the Colosseum in Rome. Assuming that finding and catching the Octopus isn't a problem.
Notes:

Yes, the setup for this is very unlikely.

The octopus isn't coming willingly

The octopus can't indefinitely breathe out of water, so its gonna need to be in water the whole way there

The temperature of the water the Octopus is in can't go higher than about 26-28 C, otherwise they'll overheat.

This sapient Octopus species has the same size and proportions as the Giant Pacific Octopus



do you mean tales?

Around Tanzania, the water temperatures only change by 4 to 5 degrees Celsius between the seasons. Are you sure this would actually make them migrate longer distances?

Around 25 C is already on the edge of what this Octopus species could feasibly live in (Bigger Octopus of their size typically live in colder waters, the Giant Pacific Octopus which I based it on for example has a max of around 15C, Maori Octopus are around 17 C), I'm just assuming that the difference even that small is enough to make even these hardy ones go back south

This has got to be one of my top 3 questions this year.
Are the the octopus especially hardy, or would they be likely to injure/die on a bumpy cart ride or (dis)embarkation?

No. (Updated)
This boils down to the following tests. Could the Romans:

Keep a large octopus alive in captivity for long periods of time?
Contain and transport live pelagic creatures aboard a ship of the era?
Ever sail a ship from Rome to the Red Sea and back?
Conduct trade with East Africa?

Previous answers have treated these questions like a checklist: if we can say "yes" to all of them, the answer to the top-level question must also be yes. Yet these aren't separate questions: when combined, the difficulty increases exponentially, to the point where I'm confident that the Romans could not achieve all of them together.
Keeping the octopus alive: they're not just fish with arms

Speaking from an aquarist's perspective, keeping octopuses (and cuttlefish) poses some distinct challenges compared to fish and other aquatic life. They're quite delicate creatures and can easily be killed in transport.
Keeping the water cold
GPOs prefer 10C water and will tolerate up to 12-13C. Your octopuses seem to be hardier in this regard, but how high can they go?
Keeping the water fresh
See e.g. Keeping cephalopods in captivity:

An octopus produces approximately three times more ammonia than a fish of a similar mass; partly due to its having three hearts and therefore three times the oxygen requirement of fish. As a result oxygen levels should always be kept as high as possible. To do this (and to remove all the excess waste) always use oversized filters and skimmers.

The most significant challenge: when they're stressed or perceive danger, they eject a cloud of ink. In an aquarium, this can quickly suffocate them unless the water is immediately scrubbed:

When an octopus feels threatened it may eject viscous ink as a smoke screen. Although it is not poisonous it can and will coat gills and this may lead to asphyxiation. The ink can often be removed by catching it in a fine net but protein skimmers and good quality carbon is a must have! Always work slowly to avoid startling a new octopus.

Perhaps your sapient octopuses can suppress this reflex, but for how long?
Feeding the octopus
They also need live food on a regular basis. GPOs can survive for long periods of time with no food, but this will increase their stress level.
Perhaps your sapient octopuses are willing to take what they can get.
Containing the octopus
A GPO needs a container of sufficient size in order to survive. The 50 gal pithoi mentioned in comments will only suffice for short periods of time; for long water journeys, you're looking at effectively building a long-term aquarium onboard, with all the attendant difficulties.
A GPO can escape through a two-inch hole: its only hard body part is its beak. They're fantastic at escaping, and human-level intelligence would only make them more so.
Heavy metals in the water
Given the metals the Romans had access to, they'd have immense difficulty building a containment vessel and associated hardware for the octopus that wouldn't poison it, considering that even a trace level of many common metals is fatal to them. There are examples in the aquarium community of cephalopods killed when their keeper put their hands in the water after touching a copper object, for example. Modern tap water that far exceeds EPA standards will readily kill invertebrates if the copper in it is not chemically detoxified. Tin is also toxic.
(Lead is also hazardous, though "what lead concentration is safe for a captive octopus" is understandably difficult to research in the modern literature.)
Considering that bronze played such a prominent role in Roman tools, and that Roman pumps and pipes were fashioned out of bronze and lead, it's hard to imagine they'd adhere to safe handling standards in this regard.
Putting this all together
Assuming this was attempted, my guess would be that the octopus would sicken and die within days, in a container that could transport live fish indefinitely with no problems. This is the modal experience for naive or unprepared octopus-keepers, even with modern aquarium technology, after all.
Even with full access to modern technology and marine science, there are many species that we cannot keep alive in aquariums. Imagine this scenario: the Romans capture a sapient octopus that doesn't want to be caught, put it in a tank on board the ship, somehow know not to use any of their most common metals in any pumps or fixtures or pipes or fasteners, are capable of pumping enough water at the right temperature and salinity through the tank to keep it alive... and then it dies because someone used a copper mug to drop its food into the tank several days ago. What's more likely: that the Romans, further from home than almost any of their compatriots have ever traveled, in barely-known territory aboard a round-hulled trading ship, would sit down and conduct a thorough post-incident review and determine the chemical cause of death, and then go and catch another octopus? Or would they conclude "octopuses just die when you put them in a tank and we don't know why"?
There's a lot more complexity I'm not getting into here. For further reading, see:

Management Guidelines for the Welfare of
Zoo Animals: The Giant Pacific Octopus Enteroctopus dofleini (PDF)
Association of Zoos and Aquariums: Giant Pacific Octopus care manual (PDF)

Keeping aquatic animals alive on board ship

While the Romans did have shipborne tanks for transporting live fish (naves vivariae), the Grado wreck is the only extant example of what may be a shipborne pump for refreshing the water, and that is disputed. See Comment on a Recent Article Concerning the Hydraulic System of the Roman Wreck at Grado, Gorizia, Italy, cited from the Maritime hydraulics in antiquity Wikipedia article. As the article states, no other naves vivariae had this capability, and it's quite likely the pump was used for something else.
Seawater to freshwater
Nonetheless, this relies on the immediate and constant availability of native seawater that sustains the animal. Even granting the existence, availability, and function of the Canal of the Pharaohs, the hypothesized route via this canal does not cross from the Red Sea directly to the Mediterranean (the Suez route). Instead, it traverses the Nile, which is freshwater. The rapid desalination of a saltwater habitat will kill almost any marine animals inside; even a minor fluctuation of salinity will do it. Octopus in particular are vulnerable. I found this article when researching lead levels in octopus: "
Abnormal mortality of octopus after a storm water event":

In summary, the results in this study showed that a short-term runoff event might change abruptly the salinity leading to the disruption of the osmoregulation function of octopus and consequently leading to its death.

In any case, "don't put freshwater in your saltwater tank unless you want everything in there to die" is Aquariums 101.
Can the Romans transport enough seawater to keep it alive for the weeks it takes to cross? Will recirculating that seawater do it? Not unless they've invented filtration of ammonia and other toxins. Can they salinate seawater to the right levels, with no test equipment (nontrivial even with modern tech, to the point where people buy seawater by the gallon for their reef tanks)? I'm maximally skeptical.
Getting there at all
The cited document, the Periplus of the Erythraean Sea, does indeed describe Roman contact and trade with East Africa. I'm not a classicist, but if you dig further into the Wikipedia article, it mentions that the author likely originated from the Roman port of Berenice; that is, on the eastern coast of Egypt itself.
Just because

the Romans traded via ship,
the Romans traded goods with East-Central Africa and the Indian subcontinent,
the Romans ever successfully took ships from the Mediterranean to the Red Sea,

it doesn't follow that the conjunction must be true, that unbroken Roman maritime trade occurred between East-Central Africa and Egypt. The red dotted line on the Wikipedia Periplus map is misleading: goods would change hands, and transports, many times over the course of the journey. See this map, from the article on Roman commerce:

Reading further into the Indo-Roman trade relations article makes it clear that the primary Roman trading ports were along the eastern coast of Egypt. My research has found no evidence of any maritime trade between the Mediterranean and the Red Sea/Indian Ocean. This article states:

Roman trade through the Red Sea corridor began in Ostia or Puteoli from which ships traveled to Alexandria and then Coptos on the Nile. It took about 20 days for the ships to reach Alexandria from Italy and another 11-12 days to move the goods down the Nile to Coptos[...]
The merchandise arriving at Coptos was carried overland by camel caravans to the Red Sea ports of Berenike and Myos Hormos. It took about seven days for the caravans to make their way to Myos Hormos (177 km or 110 mi) and twelve days to more southerly Berenike (370 km or 230 mi).[...]

Final note
GPOs really aren't that big and wouldn't be particularly spectacular to fight. They may look big in some photos, especially with their tentacles and web spread, but they're realistically a basketball-sized body connected to some tentacles considerably smaller than your arm. See this absolutely adorable video of the octopus aquarist at the Monterey Bay Aquarium caring for Chica the GPO.

The Romans probably would try to build the aquarium from earthenware, which is much easier to work with than metals. They'd probably have difficulties building a person-sized one, but they should be able to build one from multiple boards and seal the seams with something that does not kill the octopi: Tar, or resin, possibly coated with some varnish that hardens into something non-toxic. The Romans were pretty adept at adapting things to make them work, and they wouldn't think twice to experiment with enough captured specimens until they find something good enough that the "beasts" survive.

You need an aquarium of hundreds if not thousands of gallons to host an octopus of this size. The Giant Pacific Octopus at the Monterey Bay Aquarium has an enclosure the size of a small backyard swimming pool. This weighs literal tons. I'd been assuming it'd be made out of wood; I'm unaware of any watertight, much less shipborne, earthen liquid containers of this size prior to the modern era. But second, even if they did, there's still the question of pumps, fixtures, filtration, etc.: does the input water touch any heavy metals at any point? If so, slow death. Invertebrates are a challenge.

Roman hydraulic pumps were typically made of bronze or lead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maritime_hydraulics_in_antiquity . The article on the Grado shipwreck mentions lead pipes: https://rogueclassicism.com/2011/06/02/live-fishtank-in-the-grado-shipwreck/
It's important to note that there are many aquatic species today that can't be kept alive in the aquarium, and in many cases we have no idea why. We put them in a tank, give them everything we think they need, and they waste away and die. No reason to believe the ancient Romans would be any different.

I personally think the biggest problem is, as you mentioned, their infamously great talent at escaping whatever is holding them. Octopus are already natural-born Houdini's, now imagine that they have intelligence on par with humans, even if they made the enclosure the most octopus friendly place on Earth they'd still likely not be able to prevent it from escaping during the long trip to Rome. The only way I could think of it maybe working is if the cage itself was made by an Octopus, but that would require a whole new situation and circumstances

@toolforger: The ancient were great masters at making very large ceramic vessels which are called pithoi by archeologists. The typical marine pithos, used to transport grain or oil in ships, held about 200 liters or 50 US gallons; on land, even larger pithoi were used as storage containers, usually kept buried to their necks.

@AlexP Well, the largest Pithoi I could find were large enough to house an octopus, but possibly (writer's discretion) not large enough to keep them healthy enough for the Colloseum. Finding the expert Pithos maker might make for an interesting plot twist, and having to make him push the envelope might be another interesting plot twist, so that's really something to add to the answer.

I think preventing the Octopus from escaping is mainly a staffing problem. If you have armed guards at the tank 24/7, they will prevent him from escaping. And I think higher intelligence will make survival even more likely, if the Octopus wants to survive he will not do something suicidal (except of course if their culture is rather to die free than live in captivity - then the Romans would be sheer out of luck to prevent the suicide)

Updated. After doing an unreasonable amount of research, I'm now confident this would be effectively impossible.

@ChristianTernus Romans knew about the toxicity of lead, but like many EPA regulations, used it anyway because they deemed it "safe enough".  If their first few attempts at captivity failed, then they could change it out for gold which they knew was nontoxic (This was their metal of choice for surgical implants). Romans also knew about carbon filtration if buildup was a problem... which it should not be for most of the journey if they are replacing sea water with sea water.

As for the tank, they could simply make it out of tile faced concrete like they did with most of their large cisterns and add a mesh over the water fixtures.  This whole setup would weight many tons, yes, but many Roman trade ships could carry 70-600 tons; so, carrying a large tank for the octopus and a secondary tank for live fish is not that big of a deal if they are using a dedicated aquarium ship.  The hardest part will be water temperatures, but since this aspect of the species has been defined by the OP,

we are to assume he wants to go with his details rather than any real-world octopuses in this regard.  The only real limitation here is cost, but the Romans spent insane amounts of money on these fights as it was.  A skilled gladiator could sell for over five million dollars in today's currency and an exotic animal like this could go for even more; so, even if takes them a whole lot of research and investment, it could still be a worthwhile expenditure for the wealthy Senator or Emperor who decides to sponsor the fight.

Yes, the Romans were capable of transporting live aquatic animals in the 1st Century AD
According to Pliny the Elder, in Book 9 of Natural History, he describes Emperor Claudius’s fleet commander collecting live parrot fish from the Black Sea and transporting them back to the Mediterranean to create a local population closer to Rome.  Since Claudius reigned from 41AD to 54AD, we can conclusively say that Rome had this capability in the 1st century.
Based on a shipwreck found near the town of Grado, Italy we have a pretty good idea about how they did it too.  This ship contained a large aquarium onboard that was feed a fresh supply of oxygenated water by means of a hand pump.  This aquarium had a volume of 7 cubic meters and is believed to have been able to support about 200kg of live fish indefinitely. So, such a ship could have transported 2 such man-sized octopuses.
Given this capability, the Romans could have taken the octopuses from the East Coast of Africa, sailed across the Canal of the Pharaohs which connected the Red Sea to the Nile at the time, and then taken the Nile North to the Mediterranean Sea, and from there it's a straight shot to Rome.
Addressing the objections made in comments:
There is some controversy about whether or not the Canal of the Pharaohs was functional during the proposed time frame due to the story of Cleopatra sending her ship over land to reach the Red Sea.  Some claim this is because the canal was silted over, others because it was blocked by bandits, and the language regarding Hadrian's renovations make it unclear if he was restoring or redirecting the canal in the 2nd century... but all of this may be a moot point.  The story of Cleopatra sending her ship over land makes it clear that the Egyptians knew how to haul ships over land; so, even if this water way was blocked in parts, that would not automatically make it untraversable. Worst case scenario, the tank may have to go a few days without replacing any of the water while they haul the boat or transfer the octopus via a heavy wagon, but water replacement is a long-term issue. On the short term, they could just repump the water they have in the tank to keep O2 levels up. Their time spent going over land would not be enough for the tank to become dangerously contaminated.
There is also some controversy about how delicate octopuses are in captivity compared to fish. It may be necessary for the Romans to kill a lot of octopuses in captivity before they figure it out since their care requirements are not the same as fish with which they were more accustomed.  They may need to replace their typical lead pipes and pumps with gold, add larger charcoal filters, etc.  Before the Romans build their first aquarium ship, they will already have decades of experience governing Aegyptus where they will be able to start off building stationary aquariums where they can figure out most of the care issues, so that by the time someone gets the idea to send one to Rome, it's already a well established science.
... And if all else fails...
Lastly, you do not actually need to transport large octopuses to meet your goals. If 100kg giant octopuses prove too hard to transport, then they could breed the adults in Aegyptus, and just transport the eggs.  The Giant Pacific octopus lays eggs that are as small as grains of rice, take 6–7 months to hatch, and reaches maturity within two years. So instead of giant tanks and complex machinery, you could simply transport thousands of eggs in a much more simple aquarium and raise them up in Rome.  Apart from being smaller, the eggs are self contained so they have much simpler life support needs than adults.

worth noting they would need to guard an unwilling intelligent octupus of that size as it should be able to break out of such an aquarium relatively easily. transport may well be  a secondary concern.

Great answer, but note that the Canal of the Pharaohs was seemingly blocked from at least the time of Cleopatra and not reopened until Traian. That said, while fresh water would be a complication, the fairly short overland transportation seems well within the reach of Roman logistics.

Might have needed a few attempts but they should have been able to overcome those issues with a more robust tank.

@user111403 Maybe, maybe not.  It is true that Cleopatra did not take the canal, but from what I can find, she did not take it because it was overrun by bandits, but it was her first plan to escape suggesting that it was still operable during her time, even if it was not a safe or well known route.

That said, the story of Cleopatra makes it clear that the Egyptians knew how to haul ships over land; so, even if the water way was blocked in parts, that would not automatically make it untraversable.  Worst case scenario, the tank may have to go a few days without replacing any of the water, but water replacement is a long-term issue.  On the short term, they could just repump the water they have in the tank to keep O2 levels up.  Their time spent on land would not be enough for the tank to become dangerously contaminated.

The thing about taking specimens from the Black Sea to Rome is that you are sailing on salt water all the way back, so you can continually replenish the water in the aquarium.  Yes, oxygen levels are critical, but salt concentrations are also important and salt water aquaria are notoriously more difficult to keep properly than fresh water ones.  If there is an overland portion of the journey, or a portion along the (freshwater) Nile, how quickly would the salt concentration of the water move out of the tolerable range for the species?

@Kirt Yes, replacing the water and oxygenating the water are 2 different things.  You need to oxygenate it every day, but this can be done by pumping water from the tank back into it.  Replacing the water does not need to be done nearly as often.  You need to replace about 20% of the water in a saltwater tank every 1-2 weeks. At most you need to travel about 200 miles over land and brackish water which can easily be managed within that time frame.

Not sure if an aquarium on board is superior to an immerged wicker+brass cage. Well, it is while portaging, obviously. Else, not clear. The real problem is food I believe: large animals want large daily amounts and can be picky about the menu.

@FrançoisJurain dragging an animal for thousands of miles in a cage, net, etc. sounds like a good way to kill it.  Over 1 in 4 fish caught in a drag net die due to injuries, and those only pull fish a few miles before being hauled up.  A tank significantly reduces hazards associated with currents slamming the octopus against the bars.  As for food, yes, it is a concern, but no more so than all the other giant predators the Romans were able to transport; so, it should not be an insurmountable problem.

The standard requirements for water replacement and oxygenation assume a modern saltwater aquarium setup with pumps, chemical stabilization, filtration, and sterilization. None of that would be present here. As an analogy, consider ocean = human breathing free air, modern aquarium = Apollo astronaut breathing CO2-scrubbed air, ancient aquarium = human in sealed chamber, then remember what happened with Apollo 13. Octopuses produce a ton of ammonia and waste, and the only pre-modern mitigation option would be massive frequent water change.

@ChristianTernus "massive frequent water change" is exactly what the handpump did.  If an Octopus is 3 times as toxic as a fish, then 1 octopus in a 10 m^3 tank needs a total of 6 m^3 water replacement per week.  Chemical stabilization, filtration, and sterilization are mostly needed in modern tanks when using tap water, but a ship can extract already stable sea water.  At most you need to add some algae eating fish. Also, they had pumps, though they may need to sub out lead for gold to prevent the heavy metal toxicity mentioned in your answer.

Also, Romans had wagon and cranes that could move up to 10 tons; so, there is nothing stopping them from making a 10 m^3 water tank for the octopus, and putting it on 1 wagon (if the waterway is impassable) and filling up another wagon or two with replacement sea water since the passage over land and fresh water is so short. I agree that the Romans will kill a lot of Octopi trying to get the process down, but this exact kind of persistence was a cornerstone of the Roman culture.

"Chemical stabilization, filtration, and sterilization are mostly needed in modern tanks when using tap water" -- this isn't true. Modern tanks start with RODI water or filtered seawater and still need all three (stable pH/GH/KH/nitrate/nitrite/ammonia). See the octopus husbandry handbook, chapter 1.3 Water and Air Quality: " in closed systems this become much more complicated... Life support systems for octopods should be designed to process enormous quantities of waste for a given amount of biomass, but the actual turnover rate may vary anywhere between 1–5 times per hour"

@ChristianTernus And yet, I can go to the local Asian market and buy live octopus from a bucket... there is a big difference between optimal and what will kill it out right. That said, it just occurred to me that with an octopus, the eggs make a lot more since to transport than adults.  Even if you kill 99% of them in transit and from substandard care, a single clutch of eggs could still yield dozens of adults to fight in the arena without all the need for a complex aquarium ship.  A stationary aquarium in Rome makes a larger, but less complex enclosure more viable.

@Nosajimiki macerating the poor bugger in ammonia-enriched water is a sure way to kill it, too.

Market octopuses are not GPOs (large difference in biology!), were probably put in that bucket within a few days of being caught, and both the market owner and the purchaser are indifferent to whether they live out the week.

The octopus eggs, though... Now that's an interesting theory. GPO females guard their eggs until they hatch, at which point the female dies. You'd basically have to fight a sapient octopus for its eggs. There's huge story potential here!

@Nosajimiki I respect the way you're thinking of this. I'm approaching it from a "would it be historically possible given the technology" while it seems like you're saying "it isn't impossible if they wanted it enough." I'm convinced the actual ancient Romans didn't have the tech knowledge to make it work - but none of that tech is beyond the materials science they did have. At the point where they're willing to make pumps out of gold, sure, why not.

@ChristianTernus I think that is just because you don't know enough about ancient Romans.  They already had centuries of aquarium making experience for keeping non-seasonal fish and they commonly ate octopus.  We also know that you could buy live octopus in Roman markets. So, between these facts, it would be unreasonable to think that they would not have spent considerable effort at least trying to figure out how to keep octopuses in captivity long before someone decides they want them for a gladiatorial show.

We also know that Romans fully understood the the concepts of charcoal filtration, aeration, and water replacement. We also know that the Romans knew for a fact that lead is mildly toxic, they knew all the symptoms that we know now of lead poisoning, and already figured out that gold and ivory were better for medical implants than lead for being non-toxic. So, based on all the things that we do know about Romans, it would be more surprising to me if they didn't actually solve this problem IRL than if they did.

Perhaps. I'd like to see your sources (besides Pliny the Elder). I looked into the Grado wreck and it's disputed. I'd counter with "I don't think you know enough about octopus," especially since you're conflating market octopus and GPOs. I've been unable to find historical evidence of anyone keeping octopus (as opposed to fish) in captivity long-term as a specimen (as opposed to food) prior to the 19th century, and no reference to captive GPOs whatsoever prior to the modern aquarium trade.

I'll leave it to others to determine whether "they could have made pumps out of 24 karat gold!" is a real solution. (Guess what <24k gold is alloyed with?)

@ChristianTernus I did not say 24 karat gold, I just said gold.  Romans typically alloyed Gold with Silver to harden it when they needed it for implants, fillings, etc. Silver is also a biologically safe metal, and Romans knew it.

As for aquariums in the mid-19th century, they were in many ways worse than what the Romans had.  They did not have filters or aerators and they were made of wrought iron, glass, slate, and lead based putties.  If anything, this proves that you can keep an octopus alive in much worse conditions than you've thus far claimed.  I'm sure it shortens their lifespan a bit, but that is not a huge problem when your plan is to butcher them for sport anyway.

What is "biologically safe?" Silver is also toxic to marine invertebrates. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0166445X04003194
The difference between keeping an octopus alive for a week to sell at the market vs. keeping them alive for a monthslong multimodal journey over rough terrain is significant. You can transport an octopus in a plastic trash bin with ice... for hours or days, not weeks.

Can you cite any sources? I've researched Roman aquariums and read through what seems to be the main work on the subject, Higginbotham's "Piscinae: Artificial Fishponds in Roman Italy" (PDF on Anna's Archive) and nowhere is mechanical filtration or aeration mentioned - it's all accomplished through constant flow of external freshwater or saltwater. The seaborne tanks (navis vivariae) Higginbotham references were lead-lined wood with lead hardware and were built into the craft. This will work fine for most fish but will kill invertebrates.

Per Higginbotham, piscinae were notable status symbols in first-century Roman Italy. Cicero even "railed against the fishpond owners for being so preoccupied with their fish that they were neglecting the affairs of the Republic." Yet they only kept a few species, and all of them could tolerate a wide salinity range. They tried the (far-easier-to-keep, and gorgeous) parrotfish and mostly failed: "There is no doubt that attempts were made at keeping parrot wrasse in artificial enclosures, but it seems apparent that they were not cultivated with a high degree of success."

See also "The Myth of the Roman Aquarium": http://www.wetwebmedia.com/MythRomanAqKlee.htm

your citation mentions 1-50 micograms per liter which is way more than you get from simple contact with silver, much less silver alloys.  Those kinds of concentrations are typically created from mining runoff or require a colloidal silver generator to simulate.

If you're rapidly recirculating hundreds of liters of salt water through a mechanical device made with silver, you're going to get ionic silver compounds in that water. Gold-silver alloys do corrode: see https://resources.culturalheritage.org/osg-postprints/v03/selwyn/. You can reduce this corrosion by increasing the gold percentage, but at some point you end up with a pump worth the equivalent of millions of dollars on its own.

In any case: what I've discovered indicates that rare fish species were historically a status symbol in real-life Ancient Rome, with the equivalent of millions being spent on real-life piscinae - yet the range of species they did in fact keep was limited to those that could survive dramatic swings in water parameters, particularly salinity. The more complex-to-keep fish were beyond them, or so contemporary writings indicate. Do you have any sources at all that contradict this?

The ancient Romans captured and transported lots of dangerous exotic animals from as far away as India. Moving an octopus seems fairly straightforward, considering that they transported tigers and elephants - you either need a big box with a way to refresh the water regularly, or perhaps you can just drag the octopus in a net or cage behind the ship. All a bit tricky but low-tech, nothing expendable slave labor can't solve. After about the 1st century, the Romans had a Suez Canal, so they can transport it entirely by water. Before that, crossing the Suez Isthmus would be trickier, but I'm pretty confident that they'd figure it out. It's worth noting that water temperatures around the Red Sea and Suez Canal can go above your acceptable range, so you'll probably have to avoid the summer months (they might lose an octopus or two before they figure that out though).

There had been, off and on, a canal between the Red Sea and the Nile since the 700s or so BC. The canal was reconstructed by Trajan.

@elemtilas I'm aware, but before Trajan the canal had been impassable at least since the time of Cleopatra, so wasn't available to the first few emperors. Of course, if Nero really wants an octopus, maybe he sends a bunch of slaves to dig out the canal sooner and we get lots of butterfly effect fun.

@elemtilas Trajan redug it to change its course, not because it was no longer working.
The original course let out closer to the Mediterranean to prevent salt water from contaminating the Nile, but Trajan wanted a more direct route to the city of Amnis Traianus (modern day Cairo).

@Nosajimiki: We know for sure that the canal was no longer navigable in the first century BCE, because it was not available to Cleopatra when she attempted to flee after losing the battle of Actium.

@AlexP The only source I could find that specifically says why Cleopatra did not take the canal that is not blocked by a paywall says that it had been over-run by bandits.  https://www.thecollector.com/cleopatra/  Not that it was functionally inoperable.

@Nosajimiki: Plutarch, Life of Antony, 69: "The isthmus, namely, which separates the Red Sea from the Mediterranean Sea off Egypt and is considered to be the boundary between Asia and Libya, in the part where it is most constricted by the two seas and has the least width, measures three hundred furlongs. Here Cleopatra undertook to raise her fleet out of water and drag the ships across, and after launching them in the Arabian Gulf with much money and a large force, to settle in parts outside of Egypt, thus escaping war and servitude." At Perseus etc.

@AlexP Thanks, this clarifies a lot.  The fact that her ship was destroyed at Petra, and that she was trying to get to the Arabian Gulf means that she was nowhere near the Pharaohs Canal. These places are on the Eastern side of the Sinai Peninsula suggesting that her fleet was stranded in the Mediterranean and she was trying get her ships over on the far side of the Peninsula which would have been necessary if Octavian's fleet had cut her off from using the Nile.

@Nosajimiki are there any sources claiming the canal was in operation at the time? All the sources I've seen claim it was in disuse due to the Pelusiac Branch drying/silting up, which is why Traian had to connect it to a different point.

@Nosajimiki: She was trying to get her ships over the isthmus of Suez from what is now Port Said to what is now Suez. The bandits were from Petra, the ships did not get anywhere near. In the antiquity, what we call Red Sea was usually called the Arabian Gulf, Sinus Arabicus, and what they usually called the Red Sea, Mare Erythraeum, we call the Arabian Sea in the Indian Ocean. So that their Sinus Arabicus was an arm of their Mare Erythraeum. For example the famous ancient work of geography Periplus Maris Erythraei.

@AlexP Upon more research, I think you are right about what side of the peninsula she crossed.  While the city of Petra is along the Eastern isthmus, the Roman province of Petra included the entire Peninsula which makes mores since given all the other details.  That said, there are still many vague references I can find to the canal being potentially passable like Cleopatra's supposed secret water way that she could not take because it was overrun by bandits, and several sources calling the way to difficult or tedious to take as opposed to impossible.

All of the cited reasons (of Roman Authorship) that I can find about why Myos Hormos replaced Arsinoe are that main trade route with India just say that the canal was in some way a harder route to take, not that it was impassable.  All the sources are vague about what this means, and modern writers have speculated on what would make it harder.  While one of these speculations is that it was blocked off, a more credible explanation may have been the prevailing northern winds in the Red Sea simply made it harder to get to by ship.

The reason I believe Hadrian renovated the Canal in the 2nd century was because it was during this time that Romans began to transition to Lanteen sails making sailing into the wind an option which would have  made the canal a much more promising option for large trading ships.
